# Telegram Node Micro-Bot Build external API

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am trying to build an external API route to Telegram Bot with Node.

My Telegram Bot will listen to an API. When that API is called it will generate a PDF from the data and send to the Channel.

I am NOT able to find how to add API route using express to the telegrap.js bot

Any directions regarding the same is most appreciated

Thanks, in advance....